Datetime value gets truncated when converting from json to dataframe
I'm receiving some json data from an api endpoint and converting it into a dataframe. Said data has some datetime string (like 2023-05-26T05:02:16.000Z) which I'm trying to convert into a datetime object via
time = pd.to_datetime(dfmerge['date'])

but it throws me an error-
ValueError: time data "2023-05-26T05:02:16Z" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z", at position 372
This seems to be happening since the .000 in 2023-05-26T05:02:16.000Z is getting truncated. This does not seem to happen when I get the same json data from a local json file as the same code runs perfectly. Is there any way to solve this? I tried 'errors = ignore' and 'errors = coerce' but both throw assertion errors.
What the data looks like:
     ID     date                      Out
0    17721  2023-05-25T12:27:50.488Z  23012
1    17721  2023-05-25T12:28:06.568Z  19983
2    17721  2023-05-25T12:28:22.462Z  17782
372  17721  2023-05-26T05:02:16Z      16892

What my code looks like (not exact)-
response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_data')
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
time = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


How looks data in position 372? like print (df['date'].iloc[372])

it's this 2023-05-26T05:02:16Z. I'll update the table

Use time = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='mixed')

to_datetime func works slightly differently in different versions of pandas. What is your version of pandas?

@PandaKim 2.2.2
